# Cant work out why my fading script won't work

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've run across a piece of code that I'm really struggling to get working... It's meant to wait three seconds before fading an object (swslogo), however when I test it, it doesn't seem to work.. anyone know why this might be

```
    var GameMode:Number = 0;
    swslogo.alpha = .0;
    var IntroTimer = new Timer(4000,1); //add a 4 second timer
    IntroTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,swsfadein);
    intro();
    function intro(e:Event=null):void
    {
      IntroTimer.reset()
      IntroTimer.start();
    }
    function swsfadein(e:Event=null):void
    {
      IntroTimer.stop();
      swslogo.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein)
    }
      function fadein(e:Event=null){
        if(swslogo.alpha <=0){
          this.alpha +=0.1;
          if(swslogo.alpha >=1){
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadein);
          }
        }
      }
```

Edit: Removed accidental line that wasn't meant to be there

Answer (score 1):

From your last few questions I can tell you totally need to learn what a program is, in general, unrelated to AS3 of any other given language, instead of struggling with random pieces of code while treating them like magic spells.

```
// This part is fine.
var IntroTimer = new Timer(4000,1); //add a 4 second timer
IntroTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,swsfadein);

// A method is called. It resets and restarts timer.
intro();

// Another method is called. It stops the times and starts the fading thing.
swsfadein ();
```

So basically that code in a single go:

1. Creates timer.
2. Starts timer.
3. Stops timer.
4. Starts fading.

Which obviously suppresses the intended use of the timer.

Comment: Hi,  I released when typing up my code into the browser I got confused,  as the trigger for swsfade in, wasn't meant to be there.... Really sorry. Any idea how I can fix my problem?